# getTierPriceHtml of Product without loading it entirely

Tags: magento-1.9, model, html, tierprice

I have a page where where I am trying to show the tier pricing block for multiple products

I am currently loading the tierpricehtml for each product using this code...

```
<?php 
    $loadedChild = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($childId); 
        if ($loadedChild->getTierPrice()){
            echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($loadedChild)
        } 
?>
```

The issue is I have many options / customizations so loading a product entirely using the catalog/product model is very slow.  It adds about a second of load time.

Is there any way that I can use ->getTierPriceHtml with only a productID? My only other hope besides finding a way to use it without loading the product is to rip the functionality straight from tierprices.phtml and put it in my template but that feels wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're initially loading all those products via a collection then you can just call `addTierPriceData()` on it.